# How to save CQL Collection objects to Cassandra with Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, cql, apache-spark

I'm using Spark Hadoop API for fetching data from Cassandra and saving the results to Cassandra.
For row values, if the column type is long, this is the way to send data to Cassandra using CqlOutputFormat adapter for Hadoop:

```
val outVal = new java.util.ArrayList[ByteBuffer](1)
outVal.add(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(count.longValue()))
```

However when the column type is `set<text>`, I couldn't make it work. I tried to serialize java.util.Set object with ObjectOutputStream but thrift client throws `InvalidRequestException(why:string didn't validate.)`

```
val outVal = new java.util.ArrayList[ByteBuffer](1)
val byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut)
out.writeObject(data)
byteOut.close()
outVal.add(ByteBuffer.wrap(byteOut.toByteArray))
(outKey, outVal)
```

It seems it expects outVal to be a string value. I looked at the source code of SetSerializer and CollectionSerializer classes in Cassandra, it seems Cassandra uses custom serialization for Collection objects. Does Hadoop CQL3 API provide a way to serialize Collection objects or do I have to find a way to use Cassandra internal classes from outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only solution right now is copying the serialization code from Cassandra source code. Here is how Cassandra handles collection objects internally:

```
    List<ByteBuffer> bbs = new ArrayList(list.size());
    int size = 0;
    for (String elt : list)
    {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBufferUtil.bytes(elt);
        bbs.add(bb);
        size += 2 + bb.remaining();
    }

    ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 + size);
    result.putShort((short)list.size());
    for (ByteBuffer bb : bbs)
    {
        result.putShort((short)bb.remaining());
        result.put(bb.duplicate());
    }
    return (ByteBuffer)result.flip();
```